# capturing both stdout and stderr into a file and also to a console

Tags: bash, exec, tee

I am trying to make a script that spits out the status on a console as well as make a log file of that. To that end, I have been using the following line in my bash script:

```
exec > >(tee logfile.txt)
```

Having this line effectively displays stdout on a console as well as store that into a logfile.txt. Now I want to capture both stdout and stderr. I tried using

```
exec 2>&1 >(tee logfile.txt)
```

and this doesn't seem to work. Why? and how can I accomplish my task?

Answer (score 2):

Just reverse the order of redirections. It helps me to read them right to left:

```
exec > >(tee logifle.txt) 2>&1
```

Comment: First sentence and code fragment — good.  Second sentence — wrong!  The redirections are interpreted left to right.  The first one does 'process substitution' so that standard output goes to the `tee` program.  Then the `2>&1` sends standard error to the same place that standard out is currenty going (the `tee` program).  The code in the question does `2>&1` first, sending standard error to the same place that standard output is currently going, and then changes things so that standard output goes to the `tee` process (but the standard error, file descriptor 2, is still going to the console)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Well, it probably depends on how one interprets it. For me, I have to redirect stderr to stdout first, then redirect stdout to tee: otherwise, if a start by redirecting stdout, I cannot redirect stderr to it later :-) Which does not say anything about how it is implemented.

Comment: Well, the shell works left to right.  The first redirection sets file descriptor 1 (stdout) to go to the process — creates a pipe, etc. The second redirection is equivalent to `dup2(1, 2);` — it duplicates file descriptor 1 as file descriptor 2 (stderr), so both stdout and stderr are two separate file descriptors (1, 2) going to the same file (the write end of the pipe to the `tee` process).  And in reverse order, the shell first does `dup2(1, 2);` so that file descriptor 2 refers to the place where file descriptor 1 refers to (but is independent of file descriptor 1), ...[continued]

Comment: [continuation]...and then changes file descriptor 1 so it writes to the pipe that goes to the `tee` process, without changing where file descriptor 2 is pointing (which is the console, because that's where file descriptor 1 was pointing at the time the `dup2()` call was made.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: OK, adjusted the wording. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: The one tricky bit is that pipes connecting processes are detected and created before the I/O redirections are done.  That is, if you run `ls 2>&1 | tee ls.out`, then the pipe is spotted first, and two processes are connected by a pipe.  The second process doesn't have any further I/O redirection; the first has its standard error sent to its standard output, which is the write end of the pipe.